# Google Closure compiler - compile multiple files into separate minified versions

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am using Google Closure compiler to minify a bunch of js files. I only want to minify each file separately and not combine them into one. Currently I have to invoke closure compiler separately for each file. I feel I can improve the speed of build process if I could invoke closure compiler just once and pass it multiple files which it doesn't combine, but create separate minified versions of them. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different approaches to this:
1) My favorite, keep the compiler code loaded.  Nailgun does this in a generic way for for Java executables.  And this project wraps it all up:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/fast-closure-compiler

This has the advantage of working well when you need to repeated recompile the same files.

2) Create a custom command-line runner.  Here is a dated example of calling the compiler:
http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html

3) Launch multiple compiles at the same time instead of doing them serially.